# How to get image from camera roll by name/identifier in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

in my app I'm taking a picture and save it in camera roll by:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

Later in another screen, I want to display it to the user.
As I don't want to store the whole picture, is there any possibility to load an image from camera roll using the image name or an identifier? (And of course set the image name or saving the identifier when saving the picture)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge it is not possible to load an image directly from camera roll using name/identifier.

For your requirement it is better to save your image with a name in document directory instead of saving it in camera roll, then load it with the same name where ever you want to use it.

For sample code refer @Dharmesh Kheni's answer in below link.

[Get image name UIImagePickerController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953070/get-image-name-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Indeed this is working, but don't I get memory issuses when the number of stored images get too high?

Comment: if photos are too many and crossing storage capacity of phone storage then issues arise which ever method(camera roll or document directory) you are going to use. It is better to use any image compression technique if you don't consider to use that much high quality images.